# Adsense without Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, adsense

Hey I am thinking of adding Adsense to my website but the issue is that most of my users have non JavaScript phones.

The code I receive from Adsense is completely in HTML & JavaScript :

```
 <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
 <!-- home page ad -->
 <ins class ="adsbygoogle"
     style = "display : block"
     data-ad-client = "ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
     data-ad-slot = "XXXXXXXXX"
     data-ad-format = "link">
</ins>
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Is there a way for the code to be in HTML only so that all of my users can view the ad?

Comment: actually, the javascript support on modern browsers is very good.

Comment: @AbhayShukla He said this `most of my users have non Java Script phones`

Comment: Then most of your users will have non ad-infested phones as well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AdSense for Mobile](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2447276) code - if you have that option in your account. (It's not available in every country.)

> If your site supports mobile devices such as feature phones that
>   utilize WAP or i-mode, you'll need to use AdSense for mobile to
>   generate your ad code. Devices like feature phones can't render
>   JavaScript so you need to generate different ad code for them.
>   Similarly, if your mobile website supports both WAP/i-mode phones and
>   high-end devices, you'll need to use AdSense for mobile.

Add the ad code to a mobile webpage
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/66871

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can't do that:

> To view Google ads on a website, you need to have JavaScript enabled
>   in your browser. (https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/12654?hl=en)

Well, mostly because it needed to request asynchrounously from their server to achieve some algorithm like your page view, ads click, security reason, etc. And it can't be achieved without javascript. So, you need another strategy for ads on your website, like selling a space for ads maybe? Hope it help, sorry for the bad english.